# Folder upload - using angular

Tags: angularjs, file-upload, directory

How can I allow a user to upload an entire folder not just a file using angular.  I also don't want to upload a zip file. I want a user to select a folder locally and then hit upload.

Comment: What have you tried? I know you can upload all the files in a folder, but to select a folder is not allowed by the browser (security reasons).  You would have to use Flash or ActiveX or something that a user would have to explicitly allow on their machine.

Comment: Google Drive supports this feature, but only with Google Chrome. So maybe there is some non cross-browser compatible way (or maybe just Chrome can do this).